# How to set Dojo button full width

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dijit.form

I would like to add a Dojo/Dijit button widget in a Container ContentPane and have the width take up 100%. I think this should be almost trivial, but have completely failed to get any method to work while not overshooting or messing up the padding. The closest I've got is to set style

```
  fullWidthButton. .dijitButtonNode { width:100%; }

  .dijitButton.fullWidthButton {
    display: block;
  }
  .dijitButton.fullWidthButton .dijitButtonNode {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

and add the button as

```
<button class="fullWidthButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Button</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyox5rwt/4/

but this still produces a non-centered button with no padding on the right.

Any hints to what could fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to notice that the `contentPane` dijit has `padding` of `8px` in each side (16px both left and right ), which results the non centering button
to solve this , just use the css [`calc()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function , to remove the extra `16px` left and right padding from `100%` width.

See below snippet

```js
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/form/Button","dojo/parser","dijit/registry", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/domReady!"], function(BorderContainer,ContentPane, Button,parser,registry,domStyle) {
  parser.parse();
});
```

```css
.fullWidthButton {
  width:100%;
}

.fullWidthButton .dijitButtonNode {
  width :calc(100% - 16px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div id="appLayout" style="min-height:200px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
      <button id="btn" class="fullWidthButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"  type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```